# Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listview

### View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name,  ViewBag.Name as SelectList , "-- 
    Select Role", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = new SelectList (_db.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Show us your `Roles` structure, please

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at [`SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_)

```
public SelectList (System.Collections.IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```

So make sure that `Roles` model has a `Name` value.